# Creating several sets of laterally aligned equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, parcolumns

I'm just getting started into understanding TeX and the workings of it. However I am trying to write up something and I am very unsure about what to do. [image]

I have no idea where to start with this, any tips will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: are the very small spaces between pairs of primes significant, or included to make the number of primes easier to recognize, or can they be omitted without concern?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{llllll}
x^2 & x^3 & x^4 & x^5 & x^6 & x^7 \\
f''(x)=2 & f'''(x)=6 & f''''(x)=24 & f'''''(x)=120 & f''''''(x)=720 & f'''''''(x)=5040
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd invocation, I use roman numerals to denote higher-order derivatives, which is a common style I have seen.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\stackunder{x^2}{f''(x)=2}\quad
\stackunder{x^3}{f'''(x)=6}\quad
\stackunder{x^4}{f''''(x)=24}\quad
\stackunder{x^5}{f'''''(x)=120}\quad
\stackunder{x^6}{f''''''(x)=720}\quad
\stackunder{x^7}{f'''''''(x)=5040}\quad
\]
\bigskip
\[
\stackunder{x^2}{f''(x)=2}\quad
\stackunder{x^3}{f'''(x)=6}\quad
\stackunder{x^4}{f^\mathrm{(iv)}(x)=24}\quad
\stackunder{x^5}{f^\mathrm{(v)}(x)=120}\quad
\stackunder{x^6}{f^\mathrm{(vi)}(x)=720}\quad
\stackunder{x^7}{f^\mathrm{(vii)}(x)=5040}\quad
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result can be achieved with a TABstack:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\setstacktabbedgap{1em}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\tabbedstackunder[1.2\baselineskip]{x^2 & x^3 & x^4 & x^5 & x^6 & x^7}{
f''(x)=2 & f'''(x)=6 & f^\mathrm{(iv)}(x)=24 & f^\mathrm{(v)}(x)=120 &
f^\mathrm{(vi)}(x)=720 & f^\mathrm{(vii)}(x)=5040}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Still simpler with `mathtools`. I added a command for old style derivatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier,  erewhon} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{geometry}%
 \usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\osder[2]{#2^{\textsc{\scriptsize(\romannumeral #1)}}}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{matrix*}[l]
x^2 & x^3 & x^4 & x^5 & x^6 & x^7 \\
f''(x)=2 & f'''(x)=6 & f^{(\textrm{iv})}(x)=24 & f^{(\textrm{v})}(x)=120 & f^{(\textrm{vi})}(x)=720 & f^{(\textrm{vii})}(x)=5040\\[1ex]
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\text{or in old style: }} & \osder{4}{f}(x)=24 & \osder{5}{f}(x)=120 & \osder{6}{f}(x)=720 &  \osder{7}{f}(x)=5040
\end{matrix*} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]